# File share and their size - Powershell script

Tags: powershell, network-shares

So I have gotten a little further, I can now scan a folder if I type it in but scripts aren't for manual labor. I want to be able to use the command below to pull the share automatically for me.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'"  | Select path
```

BUt when i put them through the script i get an error for '@{path=e' but when i run the command i just see the folder path like i would normally want.

```
$startfolder = "E:\Learn"

foreach($folder in $startfolder){ 
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

    IF($colItems.Sum -ge 1073741824)
   {
     $folder + " --" +  " {0:n2}" -f  ($colItems.sum / 1GB) + " GigaBytes"
   }
 ELSEIF($colItems.sum -ge 1024)
    {
     $folder + " --" +  " {0:n2}" -f  ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MegaBytes"
    }
 ELSE
    {
     $folder + " --" +  " {0:n2}" -f  ($colItems.sum / 1KB) + " KiloBytes"
    }

    }
```

Comment: Are there any hidden files/folders in the dir?

Comment: Where does `$startFolder` get set? It's not getting set in the first line as one might expect.

Comment: Yes, the first line should read
$startFolder = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'"  | Select path

and should use the share output to read in thefile path of each share to display the size and location of each one but it is not.

And no hidden files of folders.